# face detection and image placing on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, face-detection

i am trying to detect face in UIImageview and place image on mouth. 
i have tried this method, but i can't transform  CoreImage Coordination system to  UIkit coordination system. here is my code:

code updated but still not functioning, just rotating view

```
@interface ProcessImageViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProcessImageViewController

@synthesize receivedImageData;
@synthesize renderImageView;
@synthesize viewToRender;
@synthesize preview;
@synthesize pancontrol;
@synthesize pinchcontrol;
@synthesize rotatecontrol;

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];



renderImageView.image = receivedImageData;
renderImageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
 }


-(void)tryAddCliparts
{
NSLog(@"button clicked");

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(markFaces:) withObject:renderImageView];

}


- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

CGFloat firstX = recognizer.view.center.x;
CGFloat firstY = recognizer.view.center.y;

CGPoint translationPoint = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
CGPoint translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX + translationPoint.x, firstY+ translationPoint.y);
CGFloat viewW = renderImageView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat viewH = renderImageView.frame.size.height;

if (translatedPoint.x<0 || translatedPoint.x>viewW)
    translatedPoint.x = renderImageView.frame.origin.x;

if (translatedPoint.y<0|| translatedPoint.y>viewH)
    translatedPoint.y = renderImageView.frame.origin.y;

recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(translatedPoint.x, translatedPoint.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];


  }
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
recognizer.scale = 1;
 }

- (IBAction)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
recognizer.rotation = 0;
 }

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
 return YES;
}

 -(void)markFaces:(UIImageView *)facePicture
{
NSLog(@"face detection started");
// draw a ci image from view
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:facePicture.image.CGImage];


// Create face detector with high accuracy
 CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary   dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];


CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform,
                                       0,-facePicture.bounds.size.height);

  // Get features from the image
  NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];
  for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features) {



    // Transform CoreImage coordinates to UIKit
    CGRect faceRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.bounds, transform);


                UIImage *mustache = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mustacheok.png"];

                UIImageView *mustacheview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:mustache];


                 mustacheview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                [mustacheview.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
                [mustacheview.layer setBorderWidth:3];
                [mustacheview addGestureRecognizer:pancontrol];
                [mustacheview addGestureRecognizer:pinchcontrol];
                [mustacheview addGestureRecognizer:rotatecontrol];
                mustacheview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

                    CGPoint mouthPos = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.mouthPosition, transform);


                [mustacheview setFrame:CGRectMake(mouthPos.x, mouthPos.y,     mustacheview.frame.size.width, mustacheview.frame.size.height)];

    [viewToRender addSubview:mustacheview];
    [viewToRender bringSubviewToFront:mustacheview];



}

}




@end
```

Comment: >when i can't transform CoreImage Coordination system to UIkit coordination system. What does that mean?

Comment: sorry i misspelled, i mean when i add image view with that coordinates to superview, image is positioned incorrectly.

Comment: what is viewToRender?

Comment: on that view faceView(imageview) is docked(fills that view) .

Comment: Why do you just use the square image detector code by apple? just replace the square image in it with your image, and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform,
                                       0,-facePicture.bounds.size.height);
for (CIFaceFeature *faceFeature in features) {

    // Transform CoreImage coordinates to UIKit
    CGRect faceRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.bounds, transform);

    if (faceFeature.hasMouthPosition) {

        // Transform CoreImage coordinates to UIKit
        CGPoint mouthPos = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(faceFeature.mouthPosition, transform);

    }

}
```

the only thing I see wrong on your code is this:

```
[mustacheview setFrame:CGRectMake(mouthPos.x, mouthPos.y,     mustacheview.frame.size.width, mustacheview.frame.size.height)];
```

you should use:

```
[mustacheview setCenter:mouthPos];
```

because the detector returns the mouth center point.

Comment: what is transform variable?

Comment: so i have tried it and it rotates image view by 180 degree. also faceRect variable is face Rectangle. i need mouth position :(


p.s if image is scaled do i need to determine scale and somehow multiply coordinates?

Comment: I think you didn't see the second transform: transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform,
                                       0,-facePicture.bounds.size.height);

Comment: it rotates imageview by 180 i changed original post with new code , can you look?

Comment: I saw it, what is viewToRender? you don't have to rotate the original photo, just the recognized coordinates

Comment: on that view faceView(imageview) is docked(fills that view) .

i removed that line, but it still rotates view:     transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform,                               0,-facePicture.bounds.size.height);

Comment: put the whole code you use, because that is incomplete. You can take a look to the code I use to store the face, eyes and mouth coordinates into an array https://github.com/jcesarmobile/faceDetect/blob/master/faceDetect/Plugins/FaceDetect.m

Comment: did you imported: #import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: But which imageview is rotated 180º?

Comment: But what is the same result? See my last update with the only thing I see that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

CoreImage uses the same coordinate system as CoreGraphics, a bottom left coordinate system, as opposed to the top left coordinate system of UIKit.

So you basically have to flip along the Y-axis (multiply with -1 and offset the height of the screen)

```
CGAffineTransformation flipVertical = 
       CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
```